# Firebase retuns incored snapshot swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase chat application and I am trying to get user credentials but I am getting wrong values from the firebase in my console

[image]

that is what my ref and snapshot is and when I decide to print this in the console I get this

```
CREDENTiL data ref Optional({
    "cc71128f-99a7-4435-879b-b1d0c7ce9c37" =     {
        location = "-Lav1QzhaoRMGAJHy8nQ";
    };
})
CREDENTiL data ref Optional({
    email = "adie.olalekan@max.ng";
    name = "Olalekan Adie";
    profilePicLink = "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/profile-icon-9.png";
})
```

this is my code

```
self.allUserRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let id = snapshot.key
                print("CREDENTiL data ref \(snapshot.value)")

                if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if snapshot.hasChild("credentials") {
                    print("CREDENTiL data \(data)")
                        if let credentials = data["credentials"]! as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            print("CREDENTiL \(credentials)")
                            if id != exceptID {
                                let userInfo = ChatUser(dictionary: data as NSDictionary)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Explain what you expect to get from firebase.

Comment: I expect to get a conversation and credentials value

Comment: The console drills down to the child of the child. values of the `credentials` and `conversation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let refer = Database.database().reference()

refer.child("chatUsers").child("your uid").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let id = snapshot.value//your snapshot
            if((((snapshot.value as! NSDictionary).allKeys) as! NSArray).contains("credentials"))
            {
                print("credentials",snapshot.value)
            }
        })
```

Please try above code to get your credentials as snapshot.

Comment: The console drills down to the child of the child. values of the `credentials` and `conversation`

Comment: can you please share your response here?